# Measuring bandwidth of a signal in R

Tags: r, signal-processing, spectrogram, spectral

I am trying to measure the bandwidth of a signal from the power spectra. I want to be able to extract the min and max values given a relative amplitude value. I have been using "seewave" to calculate the power spectra, and I can make a density plot, and provide the abline, but I cannot figure out how to get R to tell me where the abline intersects with the plot. I will need to change the relative amplitude values of interest, depending on the signal quality, but want to find a straightforward way to measure bandwidth using R. Thanks in advance!

```
power.spec <- spec(IBK.trill.1, flim=c(0,2))
pow.spec <- as.matrix(power.spec)
head(pow.spec)
#                x           y
# [1,] 0.000000000 0.007737077
# [2,] 0.007470703 0.029795630
# [3,] 0.014941406 0.021248476
# [4,] 0.022412109 0.015603801
# [5,] 0.029882813 0.014103307
# [6,] 0.037353516 0.014584454
freq <- pow.spec[1:2941,1]
head(freq)
# [1] 0.000000000 0.007470703 0.014941406 0.022412109 0.029882813 0.037353516
ampl <- pow.spec[,2]
head(ampl)
# [1] 0.007737077 0.029795630 0.021248476 0.015603801 0.014103307 0.014584454
plot(ampl ~ freq, type="l",xlim=c(0,2))
abline(h=0.45)
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to check out ?approx ... Example usage: approx(ampl, freq, xout=0.45)

Answer (score 1):

Save the results of the identification of "y" values that exceed your threshold:

```
wspec <- which( power.spec[, "y"] > 0.45)
```

Then used those indices to pull from the "x" values to place vertical lines at the first and last indices:

```
abline( v= power.spec[ c( wspec[1], tail(wspec, 1) ) , "x"],  col="blue" )
```

BTW, I suggested the original "power.spec" values rather than your `as.matrix` version because `spec` returns a matrix so coercion is not needed. I tested this on the first example from the `?spec` page. I suppose you could get real picky and try to take the mean of "x" where the thresholds were in excess and the ones just before and after. Which would then be:

```
abline( v= c( mean( myspec[ c( wspec[1]-1,  wspec[1]), "x"]) , 
            mean( myspec[ c( tail(wspec, 1), tail(wspec, 1)+1 ) , "x"]) ),  col="blue" )
```

[image]

I did look at the differences with `diff` and the typical separation in my example was

```
mean( diff(myspec[ , "x"]) )
[1] 0.0005549795
```

So I could have gone back and ahead by half that amount to get a reasonable estimate. (I used this as my estimate for "half-height": `max(myspec[, "y"])/2`)

Comment: Thank you so much! This may seem like a silly question, but how do I then extract the values where the lines are meeting the x-axis?

Comment: I don't have a way of testing that since all the y-values in the example I was using (because of your failure to include a method of getting `IBK.trill.1`) only had positive values. (And I wonder if thatis the case with your data as well.) What's `min(power.spec[,'y'])`? The answer may depend on what level of precision you need for the answer[. If you only need to know the values of indices where y[n-1] is one sign and y[n] is another sign, then it's pretty easy (but really a different question and one I suspect has already been answered.)